# Folder SysWOW64 opens on start

Tags: windows-8.1, start-screen

I am using Windows 8.1.
About a week ago, the folder kept on popping up, everytime I switched on my Laptop.
I formatted my Laptop, installing Windows 8.1, all over again.
After 2 days, the folder keeps opening at startup.
I scaned with malwarebytes, but nothing detected.
Is this something that I would be afraid of?

Comment: You formatted your HDD and after you reinstalled your operating system the same folder opens up?  Sounds like you reinstalled incompatible software twice.

Comment: The folder opened up for first time, since late 2012, the time I bought my Laptop. I was already about to format my disk. I did it, and 2 days after formatting it, the same folder popped up.

Comment: It has been a long time since someone has reported that occuring, with more cases back when win7 64bit came out. If I recall.. . Check for startup items that are non-existant or spelled wrongly like missing the extention.   Using "autoruns" might apply here well because it flags things that are missing.  Chances are good that whatever it is could be disabled with autoruns, finding it may not be so easy.

Comment: You mean that I have to check my activity log on startup?

Comment: I dont know what logs you want to look at is fine with me :-)  Take for example we put in the startup a Folder item C:\Windows , what will happen, the folder will open.  now say we tell it to run a program C:\Windows\system32\userinit (missing extention) There is no program by that name is there, so what happens? Try it in CMD prompt and you may see. The computer thinks it is a folder because that is what it looks like.  Use the program "Autoruns" or any method to view all your startup items, for something strange, missing an extention.

Comment: I followd your tip, and I found that 3 dlls are not found. What do I have to do now?

Comment: Back to the program "Autoruns" if you use it you can disable stuff and test, even save configurations.  otherwise use msconfig.exe or whatever win8 gives you to select startup items, and temporarily disable them.